# Setting env variable through script on current session

Tags: shell-script, environment-variables, source

Is there a possible way of setting env variable through script on current session.

I have tried `source` option. But this works on the shell not through script.

here is my script content

```
source /etc/profile
```

I've added a new variable in the `/etc/profile` file before executing the script, but the variable doesn't show up in the current session.

Comment: What is the command you are using to execute your script? because you said `source /etc/profile` is the script content, [unclear](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26585116#26585116)

Comment: that's what `source` does; do you mean that you execute your script (which sources /etc/profile), then your script exits, and you expect the variable to be set?

Comment: Yes Jeff! I want the variable to be present even after execution of the script.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on how you call your script.

If you are calling the script in such a way that it executes in sub shell then the variable will not be visible in the current shell.

1. try to execute the script in the current shell.

   ```
    #. ./yourscript
   ```
2. You can also source the profile by this syntax in your script

   ```
    . /etc/profile
   ```

   a dot , followed by a space and then the full path